# JavaFX retrieve index of dragged column in tableView

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, listener

I am trying to implement a listener in order to to retrieve the old and new index of a dragged column in a tableview. For this post I tried to simplify the problem as much as possible and still to have a running example.

I tried two approaches with a change and a drag listener. 
For the change listener I could not retrieve the old and new index of the dragged column. I found the change.getFrom and change.getTo values to be independent of the moved column.
In the setOnDragDropped function, The DragEvent never gets fired.

```
package TableViewColExample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.input.DragEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableViewExample extends Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      launch(args);
  }

  final TableView<String[]> tableView = new TableView<String[]>();

  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) {

      TableColumn[] columns = {new TableColumn("c1"), new TableColumn("c2"),     new TableColumn("c3"), new TableColumn("c4")};
      tableView.getColumns().setAll(columns);

      tableView.getColumns().addListener(new ListChangeListener() {

      @Override
      public void onChanged(Change change) {
          change.next();
          System.out.println("change.getFrom()"+change.getFrom()); //0 independent of moved column
          System.out.println("change.getTo()"+change.getTo()); //4 independent of moved column
          System.out.println("change.wasAdded()"+change.wasAdded()); //true
          System.out.println("change.wasRemoved()"+change.wasRemoved());  //true
          System.out.println("change.wasReplaced()"+change.wasReplaced()); //true
    }
});

          tableView.setOnDragDropped(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {

          @Override
          public void handle(DragEvent event) {
              System.out.println("OnDragDropped") ;

          } 
        }); 


    stage.setScene(new Scene(tableView));
    stage.show();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to determine old order and new order by looking at the removed and get list methods and comparing.  This may not be exactly what you are looking for but might help.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainApp extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    final TableView<String[]> tableView = new TableView<String[]>();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        TableColumn[] columns = {new TableColumn("c1"), new TableColumn("c2"),     new TableColumn("c3"), new TableColumn("c4")};
        tableView.getColumns().setAll(columns);

        tableView.getColumns().addListener(
                new ListChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onChanged(Change change) {

                        change.next();

                        System.out.println("old list");
                        System.out.println(change.getRemoved());

                        System.out.println("new list");
                        System.out.println(change.getList());
                    }

                });

        System.out.println("initial list");
        System.out.println(tableView.getColumns());
        stage.setScene(new Scene(tableView));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer above prints the references instead of the lists. Here is the code that prints the complete lists.

Conversion of matrix to string:

```
public static String matrix2String (String[][] m){
    String[] str = new String[m.length];
    for(int i=0; i < str.length;i++){
        str[i] = Arrays.toString(m[i]);
    }

    return(Arrays.toString(str));
}
```

Modified code in listener:

```
table.getColumns().addListener(
    new ListChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onChanged(Change change) {

            change.next();

            System.out.println("old list");
            System.out.println(change.getRemoved());
            List<TableColumn> removed = change.getRemoved();
            ObservableList<String[]> items = table.getItems();

            String[][] removedArray = new String[removed.size()][items.size()];

            for (int i=0; i< removed.size(); i++){
                TableColumn<String[], ?> column = removed.get(i); 

                for (int j=0; j< items.size(); j++) {

                    removedArray[i][j] = (String) column.getCellData(items.get(j));
                    //System.out.print(column.getCellData(item));
                }
            }

            List<TableColumn> added = change.getList();

            String[][] addedArray = new String[removed.size()][items.size()];
            for (int i=0; i< added.size(); i++){
                TableColumn<String[], ?> column = added.get(i); 

                for (int j=0; j< items.size(); j++) {

                    addedArray[i][j] = (String) column.getCellData(items.get(j));

                }
            }

            System.out.println("removed");
            System.out.println(matrix2String(removedArray));

            System.out.println("added");
            System.out.println(matrix2String(addedArray));

        }
});
```